# Editing an html <div> inside a PHP statement

Tags: php, html

I'm coding a PHP script supposed to create some boxes inside a webpage. I'm having problems setting the background color of the box. 
Here is the part of code involved:

```
 <div class="container">
 //$color is declared at the top of my file
   <?php
    echo '<div style="background-color: '<?='$color'?>'; width: 30px; height: 30px">'
    ?>

</div>
```

So `background-color` should take the color from the $color variable, but i don't know how to make that PHP part inside the html statement. The error i get is `syntax error, unexpected '?'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please concate your color variable with `.` Delimiter

```
<?php
  echo '<div style="background-color: '.$color.'; width: 30px; height: 30px">'
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

And another alternative:

```
<?php
    printf('<div style="background-color: %s; width: 30px; height: 30px">', $color);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $color = 'green'; //this is were your color goes ?>

    <div class="container">

      <div style="background-color: <?= $color ?>; width: 30px; height: 
       30px">
           hi <!-- Your Text Goes Here... -->
     </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way based on your original post:

```
 <div class="container">
   <div style="background-color: <?= $color ?>; width: 30px; height: 30px">
 </div>
```